# Publishing map to ArcGIS Server with time enabled data and query joining transposed data with shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, query-layer, publishing, timeslider

I am trying to figure out if I can publish my map service to ArcGIS Server that has time enabled data and uses a query table.... The query table joins my transposed time data and my shapefile. When I tried publishing it, I received the error "00004 layer's data source is not supported" and have not been able to figure it out....I have my shapefile and the transposed data in a file geodatabase....I am hoping there is some quick fix for this, but if this is not possible, is there some other option?